# Chrome extension doesn't work on chromium

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

the chrome extension

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#5d81304a17cf7ac2887484f730fbd2b01e51e166

Doesn't work on chromium, I use chromium 13.0.782.107 and when loading the extension nothing happens .

My chromium version doesn't have an arrow icon next to the extension description with a link that opens the background console and I don't know how to open it.
Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1):

The [manifest of the sample extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/basic/manifest.json) looks like:

```
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
```

The new `background` notation was [introduced in Chrome 18](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html#18), and therefore not recognised in earlier versions. Additionally, manifest version 2 was also introduced in Chrome 18, so that key is also irrelevant.

I strongly recommend to upgrade Chromium to a recent version (current stable Chromium version is 21). If you can't do that, for some reason, the manifest file has to be corrected as follows:

- Replace `"background": {...}` with `"background_page": "sample.html"`
- Rename `sample.js` to `sample.html`, and surround the contents by `<script>` tags.